# su -c no such file or directory on Android 9 aarch64

Tags: linux, bash, android, su

I have a rooted android phone use Lineage OS 16 (based on android 9). Architecture is 64 bit.

There is a file called `andraxzsh` which has the code

`su -c /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash`

Firstly `andraxzsh` is executed. Then `andraxzsh` do the code above to command the `bash` at the path above.

But the output was:

`sh: /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash: No such file or directory`

The bash file exists. When I typed:

`ls -l /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash`

Output: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 428 2018-12-06 06:01 /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash`

At root directory `root :/#` I typed

`su -c /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash`

output: `sh: /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash: no such file or directory`

There is somewhere on google they said that because the file is 32 bit and need to install 32 bit libraries for it to detect the file. I'm not sure about that, but anyway I tried to install some libs i386 on the phone and failed.

So, do you guys know a better solution for this situation?
Thank you.

Comment: I'm kind of confused by what you said about typing bash at the prompt.  That would be finding whatever bash is in your `PATH`.  What if you type `ls -l /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash`?

Comment: no I typed [path]/bash at root directory, `root:/ # /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash`.  With `ls -l /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash`, I got "no such file or directory", but if you talking about did I turn the bash file to 777, I did it already.

Comment: The file doesn't exist.  When you simply type `bash` you are getting the `bash` that exists in your `PATH` environment

Comment: Ah I understand you. You are right, when I only type `bash` anywhere it called the `bash` you are talking about. But the thing is the `bash` file in `/data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash` exists. I can see it by `ls` the `bin` folder. How can I get the `su -c` detect it?

Comment: In what bin folder?  because you said `ls -l /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash` says no file or directory, which means that file **does not** exist.

Comment: sorry I was wrong. The `ls -l` now detects it. Please take a look at this pic https://scontent.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/79374312_597443994324743_686843877121851392_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=ei223s9j61EAQl6qRUt7y5LwHP07penEvlSU_HzozLsEff2h7y9EwUOYQ&_nc_ht=scontent.fhan2-4.fna&oh=c5c7ae6be429d190a2cb33a01af37c0d&oe=5E7A1AF8

Comment: The picture is not clear but please edit your question with the relevant output as text rather than an image.

Comment: Alright. The output of `ls -l /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash` is `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 428 2018-12-06 06:01 /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash`

Comment: 428 bytes is kind of small for an executable. If you run `file /data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash` what does it output?

Comment: Hi, it's not an executable but just a `bash` file with no extension, no tail. The output of your suggested command is: `/data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash: cannot open `/data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/bin/bash' (Permission denied)`. Thought, I am now pretty sure that all of this problem because I am trying to run a 32 bit file on a 64 bit phone.

Comment: In the Unix/Linux/Android world, "executable" does not mean "a file with an .exe suffix", but "a file that can be executed". 428 bytes is surprisingly small for any modern compiled program. "32-bit" will not necessarily mean "i386" unless your hardware uses an x86 processor; you might need 32-bit **ARM** libraries instead, and there might be two types of them: `armhf` or `armel` depending on the ARM CPU model.

Comment: Thank you. I am also using another set of programs uses `armhf`, and it is running fine. With this set, I managed to run the bash file by adding `unset LD_PRELOAD` at the beginning of its code. Now the error becomes `CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "env": "/data/data/com.mytestapp/APPS/libs/libcrypto.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit`